# How to create a widget that does an action when clicked but doesn't open the application

Tags: java, android, onclick, widget

I'm new to Android programming, I've been on the subject for a few hours now but I can't find the solution. I'm trying to create a widget that when clicked does something inside the app (like the press of a "next song" button in a media player widget), but I don't want the click to trigger my application to open. Every thing that I tried so far, opened the app and didn't do what I planned to do.

Here is what I have so far :

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static final String CLICK_ACTION = "com.myproject.com.CLICK_ACTION";

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewAppWidget.class);
        intent.setAction(CLICK_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_text, pendingIntent);


        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        if (CLICK_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.d("Widget", "Launch function");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}
```

The ressource with the id "appwidget_text" is the TextView that is inside my widget.

Comment: What do you mean by "an opening of the app"?

Comment: I mean that it opens the application in question. I tried to reformulate.